# get row index in Linq query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq

I want to get the index of the row in the result set from a LINQ query.

```
int i = 0;
if (methodId == 4 || methodId == 7)
{
    sessions = db.sessions
        .Where(x => x.id == Id)
        .Select(x => new feeList
        {
            id = x.id,
            title = "Title: " + (i++)
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

I tried add a `i++` but that gives an error with message `an expression tree may not contain an assignment operator`.

How can i get the index of the row in the result set added to my `title` variable.

Answer (score 2):

(Recommend Version)Because EF LINQ not support `An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator`,so you have to use `ExecuteQuery` + SQL `row_number()` function.

```
sessions = db.ExecuteQuery<feeList>(@"
        select id,
            'Title: ' + convert(varchar(10),row_number() over (order by id)) title 
        from session where ID = {0}"
        , id).ToList();
```

(Not Recommend Version) Or if your data is small and you don't want to use sql then you can use `ToList + select((object,index)=> YourLogic)` ,because `ToList` will send SQL to DB and get data to memory then system will use `LINQ Object`,so it'll support `assignment operator` :

```
sessions = db.sessions
    .Where(x => x.id == Id).ToList()
    .Select((x,i) => new feeList
    {
        id = x.id,
        title = $"Title: {i}"
    })
    .ToList();
```

PS,index start with 0 :

```
new[] {"obj1","obj2"}.Select((obj, index) => new {obj,index})

Result : 
objc    index
obj1    0
obj2    1
```

Comment: Select((x,i) is a nice way to go for linq to objects. But for OP it's REALLY important to understand what it implies to do a ToList() at the beginning of the query and to process the following lines in memory. Another solution could be to handle the index at the SQL side, inside a view or a stored procedure for example.

Comment: yes , `ToList + Select((x,i))` only could be used in very small data,but it's still not recommend. this question should use row_number sql